# Why was this question downvoted?

Tags: discussion, question-appropriateness

I'm wondering why this question got down-voted.  I'm not completely opposed to down voting as a concept but I though it was a valid question.

[Where are the SIM Lock settings stored on an Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/5709/2573)

Any thoughts on why the community would consider this a "bad" question?

Answer (score 4):

I did not do the downvote, but I think that question is downvoted because the question is not an Android question and so is out-of-topic for this site. Also, even assuming that it is on-topic, the question does not provide enough details to provide any useful answer, such as who your carrier is and device you are using.

But, don't take the downvote too personally, people downvote for various reasons:

1. they deemed the question out of topic (e.g. carrier-specific, subjective)
2. they think the question is poorly phrased (e.g. does not have enough information to be usefully answered, or have powr speeling)
3. they deemed the question inappropriate (spams, etc)
4. they accidentally clicked the downvote and cannot change it since their vote is now locked (this is a problem with the system)
5. they just do not like the question, for whatever their own personal or political alignment (we do not like this, but there is nothing that can be done)

A single downvote does not mean the community is rejecting the question any more than a single vote means you're going to be the next president.

Comment: I get the generic up/down-vote system. I posed the question mainly as a discussion of the merits of the question mostly because I'm new to the Android.SE and I want to understand what drives the community. I'm not a big fan of the other forums that are out there for Android and I'm hoping this will become the defacto resource for android.. Anyway, thanks for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately "drive-by downvotes" do happen. If there's only one down-vote, and no one's left any explanation, then I'd just re-read my question/answer make sure everything's as clear and accurate as I can make it, and then shrug it off and ignore the down-vote.

It's not a serious matter and as Lie says, if you've only got one down-vote, then the majority of the community have no problem with your question.

Most experienced community members here regularly leave comments on questions or answers they may think aren't as clear as they could be, or may not belong here, often without down-voting initially. So it's very unlikely to be one of them who've down-voted you.

Ultimately, unless the down-voter comes here and explains their reasoning, we're really all just guessing why they did it.

Your particular question, I thought was possibly border-line whether it should be here or not, but there was no way that you (or we) could know if it was ontopic or not, without having an answer to that tells us where the sim-lock is, and whether it's Android specific. It's a bit "chicken-and-egg" you can't tell if it's ontopic until someone answers to say it is (or not), and you may not always get a good answer if someone thinks it's off-topic. Personally I'd say on-topic, obviously someone disagreed.

Comment: I guess it makes sense.. I'm glad you see my point though (the chicken-and-egg analogy was nice)

Comment: Ironically, I accidentally clicked the down-vote on this answer and almost didn't notice it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not commenting on the up/down vote as much as the assertion that several people have made that it's off-topic.  It very well may not be an Android specific question when you know the answer but I think it's clear by the way he phrased it, that he didn't know that it's not Android specific.  Personally, I think it's sufficiently related to the use of Android phones not to warrant "Off-topic" votes, especially when it's clear that the OP thinks it may be Android specific.

Comment: Agreed. [8 chs]